# python replace string ignore new line

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, replace

For example ,

```
str="dddabc
d
e
xxxx
123
345"
```

,want to replace `"abcde"` with null .
New str need to be

```
"ddd
xxxx
123
345"
```

What is the easy way to do it ?

If I drop the new line , the new string will be `dddxxxx123345` , and that wrong

This need to be on linux so it `\r\n` maybe

Answer (score 3):

Use regex [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub)

> Return the string obtained by replacing the leftmost non-overlapping
>   occurrences of pattern in string by the replacement repl. If the
>   pattern isn’t found, string is returned unchanged. repl can be a
>   string or a function; if it is a string, any backslash escapes in it
>   are processed.

```
import re
st="""dddabc
d
e
xxxx
123
345
"""
rep="abcde"
print(re.sub(r'\n?'.join(rep),r'',st))
```

OUTPUT

```
ddd
xxxx
123
345
```

Comment: @devohourse I have made the changes , earlier I didnt use raw strings now I did. That caused the error :-).

Comment: that but wtill I get same error , maybe because that need to work on linux and there break line is `\r\n` ?

Comment: @devohourse line break is always `\n` now if you are unsure about this type `print(repr(string))` to print the underlying representation

Answer (score 1):

Use regex as so :

```
new_str = re.sub('a(\s)*b(\s)*c(\s)*d(\s)*e(\s)*', "", str)
```